# Navigate when Angular Material dialog box opens

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to display some data to dialog and to do this, I need to give a navigation with some `id` parameters when I open the dialog.

Is there a way to navigate when the material dialog opens?

Comment: You can pass a component to the dialogservice

Comment: I want the URL to change, like it changes when u navigate to a ordinary component

Comment: So then wrap the dialog in a new component, and route to that component

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to function afterOpen() which is Observable from dialog-ref, and inside that function you can navigate to specific url.